# Best way to make sure several arrays are the same length

Tags: java, arrays

For reasons that I'd rather not go into, I have a bunch of parallel arrays and I'm curious what the most elegant way to go about making sure that they are all the same length would be.
(if one of them is the wrong length then there must be data missing and the arrays won't align properly).

I don't like the idea of doing...

```
if(array1.length != array2.length || array1.length != array3.length etc...)
```

That just looks dreadful, I'm really hoping there's a more elegant way...

My impulse is to add their lengths together and divide by the total number of arrays and see if that number is the same as one of the array lengths, but I'm open to suggestion (as well as to be told that my idea won't work for some reason that I've overlooked).

I'm in Java, but I suspect that the answer to this question is language agnostic.

Comment: I *guess* you already know this, but the correct solution is "don't use parallel arrays".

Comment: You impulse wouldn't work either: if you have arrays of length 2, 1 and 3, the average would be 2, the same as the first array, yet they all have different lengths.

Comment: Well what you have said is utterly useless --Dr. Dredel. The author has specifically said that he has to use parallel arrays for some reason. Sometimes you have to break a few lofty ideas of programming for ease, practical needs and dependency constraints.

Comment: as you surmised... I'm not thrilled about that at all... but I'm in someone else's code and can't unwind this particular ball of yarn. Still, I'd like to have an answer to this question, if only to know if there's some really nice way to compare a bunch of things for equality in one elegant test.

Comment: @andrew... thanks... that's precisely the example of "not gonna' cut it" I was hoping for... I'll blame not having thought of it myself on this being my 15th hour in front of my screen today :)

Comment: @user496934: I *know* that it's not always possible, but far too many beginners use parallels arrays when there *is* a better solution. And if one of those stumbles upon this question, they should be *told* that they should *at least* reconsider that design.

Comment: Just had another thought... Shouldn't &(ing) all their lengths produce the same number as any of them? ie. (len1 & len2 & len3 & len_n... == len1)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: no, you'll get false positives: try it with 2 and 3: `2 & 3 == 2`. And `|` won't work either: `3 | 2 == 3`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a method like this (using [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html)):

```
 import java.lang.reflect.Array;

 /**
  * Checks an arbitrary number of parallel arrays to verify that they have the same length.
  * @throws IllegalArgumentException if any of the arguments is not an array or if the lengths of the arrays are not equal.
  */
 public static void checkParallelArrays(Object... arrays) {
   if (arrays.length < 1) {
     return;
   }
   int expectedLength = Array.getLength(arrays[0]);
   for (int i=1; i<arrays.length; i++) {
     int length = Array.getLength(arrays[i]);
     if (length != expectedLength) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array " + i + " doesn't have expected length " + expectedLength + ": " + length);
     }
   }
 }
```

Note that the parameter type is `Object` to allow primtive arrays (`int[]`, `char[]`, ...) as well. If you could restrict the parameters to reference type arrays only, then that would simplify the code quite a bit.

Comment: Nice +1. (1) Wouldn't be better to return a boolean? (2) Shouldn't the test be `if (arrays.length < 1)`?

Comment: @Jiri, if you pass it less than two arrays, (i.e. one or zero) all of those are obviously of equal length.

Comment: @Jiri: I prefer an exception, because a `boolean` return value is too easy to ignore and the exception has a bit more information. It depends on your design choices, however. And I *had* `length < 1`, but if `arrays` contains a single array, then it has by definition the correct number of elements. The only case that is not  tested then is if the single argument is not an array.

Comment: @Jiri: I changed it back to `< 1` so that it checks the case where you call it the wrong way (e.g. `checkAParallelArrays("foo")` should throw an `IllegalArgumentException`).

Comment: shouldn't it be arrays.length <= 1? Since no arrays or a single array are the trivial cases?

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean checkLength(Collection myArrayCollection){
    Iterator myIterator = myArrayCollection.iterator(); 
    Object o = myIterator.next(); 
    int length = (Object[])o.length; 
    while(myIterator.hasNext()){
        o = myIterator.next();
        if(length!= (Object[])o.length)
            return false; 
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Of course, there might be syntax errors in there (you might have to cast to Object[] before trying to take the length), and some semantic errors (like catching casting exceptions).  But you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

A simple variation of Joachim's code:

```
public static boolean areSameLength(Object[]... arrays) {
      int N = arrays[0].length;
      for (Object[] a : arrays)
         if (a.length != N)
            return false;
       return true;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to check the length attribute of all the arrays and see if they are all the same.  Suppose the arrays are String s[], Object s2[], int[] s3, the  just use s.length == s1.length and so forth.